# Data persistence issue in SQL database using .Net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a problem persisting data in the SQL database from .Net core API application.

I am using generic repository pattern where generic repository class takes TContext as a parameter and instantiates corresponding db context.

This is what my generic repository looks like:

```
public abstract class Repository<TContext, TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
```

Inside the class I have a method for instantiating given db context:

```
public TContext CreateContext() {
    return (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), Options);
}
```

And I am wrapping CreateContext method in using statement to instantiate db context:

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity) {
    using (var context = CreateContext()) {
        var added = context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return added.Entity;
    }
}
```

I have a complex entity which contains several other entities (related data). When API receives calls for updating related entities in a sequential order, everything works fine, entries in database are updated.

Although, problem appears when API gets simultaneous calls for several related entities at the same time. While debugging step-by-step, I can notice that database entries are being updated, but when API returns response, I'm still getting old values and database entries are overwritten with old values again.

I couldn't come up with the solution to this problem other than wait for each call to complete and make calls in a sequential order, which is quite a performance hit.

Application is running using .Net core 2.2.

Comment: Is there a reason you are newing up your context with every repository call? Look into the `Unit of Work` pattern.

Comment: Well, this is pretty commonly used approach of DbContext usage as I've seen many examples involving such approach. What I don't understand is that completely different entity operations interfere with each other and influence the outcome of the operations. Could you elaborate how UoW would help in my case?